# How is the subjective warning popup determined for a question?

Tags: support, quality-filter, popups

Today I have noticed a subjective popup warning while asking a question on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/what-is-the-difference-between-the-ending-of-the-novel-kimball-ravenswood-and-th)

[image]

I tried with a different wording for the same question but the result was the same

[image]

It's not site specific as I have tried the same on scifi.SE with same results.

I haven't seen it before, is it some new feature? And what is the algorithm for this popup to appear? Any guidelines for it?

Comment: The "what's your" triggers the alert, but you can ignore it. (Since it's just part of a movie name.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh, that might be worth an answer if fleshed out a little more.

Comment: @Christian no need, it's already answered in the dupe. (Would have posted answer if there wasn't the dupe)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Honestly that duplicate seems rather crap, and it doesn't seem to answer this specific case at all.

Comment: @Christian like any SE site, most contents here are not specific, but rather general. Anyway, for me it's clear enough, but you can post a new answer there with a better explanation. :)